# Is there a way to get the same output on a foxxservice as on the arangosh?

Tags: arangodb-foxx

The goal is to develop a `foxxservice` that simply delivers the available user collections in `json`.

What I've already tried: Set up local `arangodb` server. Then read the documentation and use the `arangosh` to try the commands. Then extended the `foxxservice` hello world example to get the same output.

```
arangosh

127.0.0.1:8529@TestDatabase> db._collections()

[ 

  [ArangoCollection 2393976, "_appbundles" (type document, status loaded)], 

  [ArangoCollection 2393973, "_apps" (type document, status loaded)], 

  [ArangoCollection 2393961, "_aqlfunctions" (type document, status unloaded)], 

  [ArangoCollection 2394097, "_fishbowl" (type document, status loaded)],

  [ArangoCollection 2393964, "_frontend" (type document, status loaded)], 

  [ArangoCollection 2393943, "_graphs" (type document, status loaded)], 

  [ArangoCollection 2393970, "_jobs" (type document, status loaded)], 

  [ArangoCollection 2393948, "_modules" (type document, status loaded)],

  [ArangoCollection 2393967, "_queues" (type document, status loaded)], 

  [ArangoCollection 2393951, "_routing" (type document, status loaded)], 

  [ArangoCollection 2394131, "Relation" (type edge, status loaded)], 

  [ArangoCollection 2394114, "Table" (type document, status loaded)] 

]
```

**The foxxservice:**

```
'use strict';

const createRouter = require('@arangodb/foxx/router');

const db = require('@arangodb').db;

const router = createRouter();

module.context.use(router);

router.get('/hello-world', function (req, res) {

  res.send('Hello World!');

  const collections = db._collections();

  res.json(collections);

})

.response(['application/json'], 'A generic greeting.')

.summary('Generic greeting')

.description('Prints a generic greeting.');
```

Actually, I was expecting the same json. Hopefully it is not impossible for safety reasons.

But this is what the browser shows:

```
[
{"_id":"2393976","_dbName":"TestDatabase"},

{"_id":"2393973","_dbName":"TestDatabase"},

{"_id":"2393961","_dbName":"TestDatabase"},

{"_id":"2394097","_dbName":"TestDatabase"},

{"_id":"2393964","_dbName":"TestDatabase"},

{"_id":"2393943","_dbName":"TestDatabase"},

{"_id":"2393970","_dbName":"TestDatabase"},

{"_id":"2393948","_dbName":"TestDatabase"},

{"_id":"2393967","_dbName":"TestDatabase"},

{"_id":"2393951","_dbName":"TestDatabase"},

{"_id":"2394131","_dbName":"TestDatabase"},

{"_id":"2394114","_dbName":"TestDatabase"}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Possible solution:**

```
'use strict';
const createRouter = require('@arangodb/foxx/router');
const db = require('@arangodb').db;
const router = createRouter();
module.context.use(router);
router.get('/hello-world', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Hello World!');
    var collections = [];
    db._collections().forEach(function(element) { 
        if(!element.name().startsWith("_")) {
            var obj = {};
            obj[element._id] = element.name();
            collections.push(obj);
        }
    });
    res.json(collections);
})
.response(['application/json'], 'A generic greeting.')
.summary('Generic greeting')
.description('Prints a generic greeting.');
```

**The generated output:**

```
[
    {"2394131":"Relation"},
    {"2394114":"Table"}
]
```